# How to crack EncryptedLocalStore in Adobe Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, security, mobile, actionscript

Assume user Tom installed an Adobe Air app named X, and X stores some secret in EncryptedLocalStore; then Tom wants to crack EncryptedLocalStore (inspect and alter its content), how could he do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, but why would he want to do that?  It sounds a little like "tell me how I can open up the secrets cache for Air program X because I want to get data I'm not supposed to be able to get to"?

Comment: Just a crack, you know. Normal user will not do this but I must take security into consideration. If EncryptedLocalStore has its weakness, I may switch to other solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to AS3 language reference:

> The data in the encrypted local store is protected by the user’s operating system account credentials. **Other entities cannot access the data in the store unless they can login as that user**. However, the data is not secure against access by other applications run by an authenticated user. Thus, data that your application may want to keep secret from users, such as keys used for licensing or digital rights management, is not secure. The ELS is not an appropriate location for storing such information. It is only an appropriate place for storing a user’s private data, such as passwords.

Some notes about encryption:

> AIR uses **DPAPI on Windows**, **KeyChain on Mac OS and iOS**, and **KeyRing or KWallet on Linux** to associate the encrypted local store to each application and user.
>
> The encrypted local store uses **AES-CBC 128-bit encryption**.
>
> **On Android, the data stored by the EncryptedLocalStorage class are not encrypted**.

Let's summarize:

- If someone can login to the user account, he can access the `EncryptedLocalStore`
- The `EncryptedLocalStore` is managed by the operating system, not AIR
- Data are encrypted but not on Android

If you want to crack such storage you would have to:

- Retrieve the content of the storage
- Break the encryption (which is pretty good)
- Find specification about parsing such data repository
- Write your own data reader

Comment: It's somewhat confusing to me. Are you saying that other applications can read that information? Does that mean my application can read sensitive data from other applications? ...and that's simply because the user is logged in? That doesn't sound right (maybe it is). But I would think if an application adds sensitive data to the keychain only that application should be able to retrieve it IMHO.