# How would you secure data in your AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

My client wants to store his login in the Adobe AIR application. Is this a good idea? I've looked at using Encrypted Local Storage (which uses the operating system) or is there another method more suitable?

I've found this answer but it is very confusing, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899254/441016. It is saying it is OK to use to store login information but not OK to store registration keys for licensing software. I don't understand that. Login is more important than registration keys.

It's saying that other applications can read that information. Does that mean my application can read sensitive data from other applications simply because the user is logged in? That doesn't sound right. If an application adds sensitive data to the keychain it should be the only application that can retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Encrypted Local Storage for saving login information in the device, it's save and easy to use.

If some user is able to see the contents in the Encrypted Local Storage (ELS), all he will see, is his own login info, so there isn't a security risk here. However, if you save registration keys or API keys, the user could use this information to hack your App.

Hope this helps.